# atmega8a-pu PORTC not working in 3v3

Tags: avr, atmega, 3.3v

I have `atmega8a-pu` and not problem with `5v`.

but when i connect `3v3` to `atmega` my `PORTC.0,PORTC.1,PORTC.2,PORTC.3` and `PORTC.6` have not very good output!!!

See this image, in image each two circuits is connected to 3v3 supply...
[image: my led in 3v3]
<sub>(source: [bayanbox.ir](https://bayanbox.ir/view/4088463064406694923/Untitled-1-copy-copy.jpg))</sub>

But    `portc.5`  has a good voltage and  `portc.3` doesn't have good voltage

I set this variable to my code:

```
PORTC=0x00;
DDRC=0x7F;
PORTC=0b1111111;
```

What is the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we want use `PORT C (3..0)` , we must connect `avcc` to `vcc`

> AV CC  is the supply voltage pin for the A/D Converter, Port C (3..0),
>   and ADC (7..6). It should be externally connected to V CC , even if
>   the ADC is not used. If the ADC is used, it should be con- nected to V
>   CC  through a low-pass filter. Note that Port C (5..4) use digital
>   supply voltage, V CC .

[source atmega8 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/atmel-2486-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega8_l_datasheet.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

In case both are supposed to be 3.3, measure the volt drop across both leds, one will be lower than the other. Also see what the supply voltage is during the firing of the led is for both ports.

Comment: But the resistor isn't very high (220 Ohm). Even with 1K resistor, my 3.3 V STM32 still make that kind of LED glow brightly.